# Limit Sending Push Notification (Prevent Spam) - GCM

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, spam-prevention

Well I have an android app like social network,I m using GCM, to send push notification,

When a User A follow User B , User B will receive notification saying "that User A has started following you".

Now I'm trying to prevent abusing/spamming sending multiple push notification.like follow and unfollow follow again and so on.

What is the best approach to tackle this problem .because I don't want my users to get abused receiving multiple notifications.

I've tried to look for a perfect solution regarding this issue.Unfortunately I can't find any answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can send notification to user just one time for follow and for unflallow, Then you should not send any notification for that , because it is not valuable information.

Comment: How I m supposed to do it . I m using PHP to SEND notifications, and I don't know how i can keep track whether a user has already followed another user before ??

Comment: you can keep track easily, I think you have server and you can use web api and you can save whatever you want. Before you send the notification you can post your web api and save your data which someone follow/unfollow other one.and before the send your notification use your own get api to check you should send the notification or not.